# A company's most important person in a specific task

Tags: expressions, idioms

Please suppose that the following image is a company including all of its staff, supporters, leaders and key members where the bowman and the bow and the arrow are the whole company including all the parts I mentioned and the final goal is hitting the target with the arrow at hand. This arrow as a simile can be comprised of some quite significant members, (e.g. some ambassadors of a diplomatic group which are supposed to go abroad for some vital negotiations with one of the worlds leading manufacturers in a specific industry for the most beneficial contract ever in the history of the company.)

As you see, the arrow is composed of three main parts:

1. **Tip** (The most important part in direction.)
2. Shaft
3. Fletching

Can we be inspired by this fact and use it as a simile in English for a very **key member (the arrow's tip)** in an organizational activity who may/may not have the most important position in the company's hierarchy, but acting the lead role in a particular task/department/mission etc.?

I can think of several similar terms in English, but I'm not sure if we can use them in this sense:

> **a.** I'm **in the vanguard of** company's whole affairs and the second person after the company's owner/ CEO. 
>   **b.** I'm **at the forefront of** company's whole affairs and the second person after the company's owner/ CEO. 
>   **c.** I'm **at the foremost position of** the company's whole affairs and the second person after the company's owner/ CEO. 
>   **d.** I'm **in the leading edge of** the company's whole affairs and the second person after the company's owner/ CEO. 
>   **e.** I'm **in the cutting edge of** the company's whole affairs and the second person after the company's owner/ CEO.

If none of them works, then I wonder what idiom/expression or probabely fixed phrase would you say in idiomatic and normal way for this situation.[image]

Comment: I think "key players" is fairly idiomatic in this sense.

Comment: Thank you @Hot Licks, but why the other phrases do not work in your mind or are less acceptable?

Comment: Why do you think the tip of an arrow is more important than the fletching in setting direction?

Comment: Because that's usually the first point that hits the spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're the **point person**. Merriam-Webster:

> : point man sense 2

which is

> 2 : one who is in the forefront especially : a principal spokesman or advocate
>
> (example) the *point man* for the President's economic policy

A point person leads an initiative, a task, or something else. That person tends to field inquiries and make decisions about that area of focus.

In comparison, your examples 4 and 5 (*cutting/leading edge*) use expressions that would tend to pertain to technology and development. 3 and 2 (*foremost/forefront*) are positionally appropriate but make it sound like you're in a race with your colleagues and coworkers; the connotation is competitive. 1 (*vanguard*) is close to what you want (lead from the front), but has a more militaristic connotation (who are you attacking? what are you protecting?). **Point person** signals a strong operational position and sounds task-oriented.

Comment: Yes! I do agree. If I'm not mistaken @TaliesinMerlin, I confronted with "foremost" and "forefront" in quite similar cases. For instance, "He held the foremost/forefront position of the tribe / of the company / etc."! They are pretty much interchangeable to me in this sense.